# postfix - How to create truly user based rules for limiting?

Tags: postfix, rules

I have a mail server (postfix 2.9.6) up and running with 15-20 users, only for internal usage with one single domain, let's call it xyz.mail.lan

Users are:

```
    user1@xyz.mail.lan
    user2@xyz.mail.lan
    user3@xyz.mail.lan
    …
    user5@xyz.mail.lan
```

No external relay, or incoming mails from internet side is necessary. It works fine right now.

**My goal is to limit the users in sending mails to each other.**

For example:

- user1 is allowed to send mails only to: user2, user3, user4, user5
- user2 is allowed to send mails only to: user1, user3
- user3 is allowed to send mails only to: user1, user5
- …
- user5 is allowed to send mails only to: user1, user4

I will not have more than 20 users, so I don't mind if my hands has to be dirty with setting up ugly rules for each user.

Comment: You might be able to use procmail for this, but I'm not sure where it would fit in as I don't have the full picture. Are you using something like dovecot for mailbox access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to quick and dirty solution (because of few user) and without external script/daemon (just using postfix and its maps), take a look in [Postfix Restriction Classes](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html). In that page, you should see examples how that feature works. In short, **every class will have own set of restriction** just like you want.

For your case, first you will add this checks table in `smtpd_*_restriction`, for example smtpd_recipient_restriction

```
smtpd_recipient_restriction = 
           ... other restriction....
           check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_rules

smtpd_restriction_classes = user1_rule, user2_rule, user3_rule,...

user1_rule = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/rules/user1
user2_rule = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/rules/user2
user3_rule = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/rules/user3
so on...
```

Content of **/etc/postfix/sender_rules**

```
user1     user1_rule
user2     user2_rule
user3     user3_rule
... others ...
```

The last is the content of /etc/postfix/rules/userX (where X is 1... number of users)

**/etc/postfix/rules/user1**

```
user2    OK
user3    OK
user4    OK
user5    OK
```

**/etc/postfix/rules/user2**

```
user1    OK
user3    OK
```

And the others...

Comment: Thanks for your input. I followed your advice, but no luck. I successfully generated the db files with postmap command, no errors with your config in syslog but the rules are simply not applied, mailes goes through against them. I think my problem is the "smtpd_recipient_restriction" line, I can't find a "sufficient-to-set" configuration that plays with your "check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_rules" rule.

Comment: Disregard my previous message.
I had to set full names like user1@xyz.mail.lan instead of user1 in /etc/postfix/sender_rules and in the /etc/postfix/rules/userX files
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Since your use case is very special and standard Postfix lookup methods do not work for you, I would consider using Postfix [content inspection](http://www.postfix.org/CONTENT_INSPECTION_README.html).

Usually it is used for anti-spam/virus filtering, but since you can hook up your own Perl/whatever scripts to it, you can create a small script with the language you like and let it answer to Postfix if the mail should be passed or not.

In pseudo-code, something like

```
if ($mailfrom == "user2" && ($rcptto == $user3 || $rcptto == $user5)) {
    yes_pass_the_mail();
}
```

should do. Take a look at Postfix documentation about filtering.

Comment: Thank You for pointing me to this direction. It is a half solution. I succeeded to create the filtering stuff depending on the header content, but there is a backdoor in this solution: BCC recipients. BCC addresses are not listed in headers.